# Get value from <span> tag on external page using Javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, html

I have an internal webpage for my team which currently has an iframe which shows a small section of our ticketing site to show how many unassigned tickets are in our queues.

I find this iframe to be quite an eyesore and I would like to simply have text that gets the number from our ticketing site and outputs that as plain text on my page.

I know that, on the external page, the value I want is in:

html > body.view.views-show > div#page > div > div#container.clearfix > div#contentwrapper > div#contentcolumn > div#content.content-grey > h2 > span.item-count

From my schooling days I would use something like GetElementById for this, but that only applies to the page the script is on.  How would I do something like this for an external site?

Answer (score 0):

In that case you have to request the page by:

```
$.get(url, function (html) {
  var $html = $(html);
  console.log($html.find('span.item_count').text());
});
```

Comment: So, would that look something like this (I'm not too experienced with jQuery):  

`<script>  
$.get('http://address/', function (html) {
var $html = $(html);
$html.find('span.item_count').text();
});
</script>`

Comment: Yes, that's the correct syntax (assuming you have jQuery lib included off course).

Comment: Okay, great.  I have that in place.  I don't see any text though on the page, an no errors coming up in the console.  Is there something else I need to to to print the value to the page?

Comment: I've updated my code example. You should do 'something' with the found html() value. In my example I've added console.log, so you should now see something in your console. Otherwise check your 'Network' tab en look for XHR requests.