# How To Load One Section of External Site in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, iframe

I want to Load One Section of External Site in My Site ASP.NET Core?
for example load one span tag of External Site in the project.

Comment: I didn't undestand, can you explain in another way?

Comment: Look into : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19965147/get-value-from-span-tag-on-external-page-using-javascript-jquery

Comment: for example i have an project and other site is example.com i want load numbers or span tags or other values to my project not all  example.com